# TeamCity and TFS Feature Branches

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I have an easy branching setup in TFS 2012 like so:

$/Dev
$/Dev/Feature1
$/Dev/FeatureFoo
$/Dev/FeatureBar

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get TeamCity (v8) to trigger a build for my feature branches, **without checking out the entire VCS root** ($/Dev).  Since you can't have wildcards in checkout rules, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger rule for that. Go to "Add New Trigger" and add a new Trigger Rule:

+:logical branch name

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-TriggerRulesExample

You can also look at following article about working with Feature branches:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-logicalBranchName

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really solve my main problem: "without checking out the entire VCS root".  Because the number of branches is always dynamic, I want the checkout rules to be dynamic.

Comment: If you always have a prefix "Feature" then you can use +:Feature* or also probably do it bad on folder path...

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't change the fact that $/Dev/* still gets checked out with the build.  Do you know how to make it so only the branch that gets triggered, is the only branch that gets checked out?

Comment: For that I think you will have to create a folder for all feature branches and then use that folder in the "Root" property on the Version Control Settings page.